# How to pick a files based on the first received in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have some file in a folder, and I want to pick that file one by one consider to first received (FIFO  method). I tried this code, but the file pick randomly but does not consider the first received. I dont finish pick all the file, and I receive a new file, it already pick the new one.
Anyone can help me please. Thanks

```
$Op_Path = "D:\Auto\Process"
$ID = "01"
$Pick = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Op_Path\$ID\*.txt"
$count = 1
$Get = Get-Random -InputObject $Pick -Count $count | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime}
$Rename = $Get | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$Op_Path\$ID\$($_.BaseName).don"}
```

Comment: You can use creation time,,some thing like below `Get-ChildItem -Path 'somepath' -Recurse  |Select-Object CreationTime | Sort-Object -Property creationtime `

Comment: why not just `rename *.txt *.don` if that doesn't work, just put it through cmd.exe `cmd.exe -c 'rename *.txt *.don'`  --- also foreach does FIFO, if that helps?

Comment: Hi @TheGameiswar , I try creationtime, but it still the same thing as lastwritetime. I want to pick the job consider to `Date Modified`

Comment: @RobertCotterman my problem is to pick the file based on the Date modified

Comment: just sort by datemodified `$Pick = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Op_Path\$ID\*.txt" | sort "lastwritetime"` if you want reverse sort, add `-descending` to the sort command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your responses, this should be your script

```
$Op_Path = "D:\Auto\Process"
$ID = "01"
$Pick = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Op_Path\$ID\*.txt" | sort "LastWriteTime"
ForEach ($item in $Pick) {
    Rename-Item -Path $item.FullName -NewName "$Op_Path\$ID\$($item.BaseName).don"
}
```

Comment: But I want to pick the files one by one, and modified the extension file one by one, because after I modified it, I want to read the file and do some process, that's why I use random to get one by one the file @Robert