# How to select file and read the content ordering by date received using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have some file in a folder. I want to select file and read the content ordering by date received. I tried this, but I can not select one by one file. It select all the files.

```
$Path = "D:\Auto\File"
$Pick = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path\*.don"  | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
$Pick
$ReadFile = Get-Content $Pick
$ReadFile
```

This is the result:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        8/13/2019  12:48 PM              6 1.don
-a----        8/13/2019  12:48 PM              4 2.don
-a----        8/13/2019  12:48 PM              3 3.don
-a----        8/13/2019  12:48 PM              3 4.don
111111
2222
333
444
```

My expectation, I can read the file one by one, based on the file, I can read file `1.don` first, then `2.don` and so on.

Comment: [1] where did `$PickJob` come from and what is in it? [2] if you wnat to process in date & then name order ... why don't you sort by those values? or perhaps use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group by date and then sort the groups by file name?

Comment: [1] I did some typo. It means $Pick. [2] I dont want to order by name, I just need to order by date received. I give the example I can read `1.don` first because when I print `$Pick` it shows `1.don` file first. But the fact, file name is not always 1,2, or 3.

Comment: ah! thanks for the info! [*grin*] --- try iterating over the `$Pick` collection. a  `foreach ($File in $Pick) {Get-Content -LiteralPath $File.FullName}` looks like it would work.

Comment: Did you not see what @RobertCotterman answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470288/how-to-pick-a-files-based-on-the-first-received-in-powershell)? Both Lee_Daily and Robert suggest you loop over the files and do your processing inside the loop.